# Python html div class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a simple program which saves the values of a table in a matrix (later I want to send the matrix to a database).

Here is my code:

```
pfad = "https://business.facebook.com/ads/manager/account/ads/?act=516059741896803&pid=p2&report_spec=6056690557117&business_id=401807279988717"
html = urlopen(pfad)
r=requests.get(pfad)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),'html.parser')
mydivs = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "ellipsis_1ha3" })

# no output:
for div in mydivs: 
    if (div["class"]=="ellipsis_1ha3"):
        print div
# output: []
print(mydivs)
```

I want the values inside of the `div`s with class `ellipsis _1ha3`, but I don't know why it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Here is an example html which is like the original

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        .ellipsis_1ha3 
        {
            width: 100px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .a      
        {
            width: 100px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <div style="display: inline-flex;">
        <div class="a">Purchase</div>
        <div class="a">Clicks</div>
    </div>
    </br>
    <div style="display: inline-flex;">
        <div class="ellipsis_1ha3">20</div>
        <div class="ellipsis_1ha3">30</div>
    </div>
    </br>
    <div style="display: inline-flex;">
        <div class="ellipsis_1ha3">10</div>
        <div class="ellipsis_1ha3">50</div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

SECOND EXAMPLE

```
pfad = "http://www.bundesliga.de/de/liga/tabelle/"
html = urlopen(pfad)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),'html.parser')
mydivs = soup.findAll('div', { 'class' : 'wwe-cursor-pointer' })
for div in mydivs: 
    if ("wwe-cursor-pointer" in div["class"]):
        print div
```

Comment: You'll should add some example input HTML; see [mcve].

Comment: ok wait i edit with an example html

Comment: sorry i cant do it better. divs arent allowed.

Comment: Put it in a code block by indenting it with four spaces. You can use the button in the toolbar or CTRL+K to do that.

Comment: At any rate, the problem seems to be that in the HTML you use `ellipsis_1ha3`, and in the Python code you have `ellipsis _1ha3`. There's an extra space there.

Comment: i did the extra space only for using css. actually there is a space.

Comment: now everythink is fine. thank u for the support :) have anyone an idea for my problem?

Comment: Your example basically works ([example](http://pastebin.com/sgvJ8TsG)), except that `div["class"]=="ellipsis_1ha3"` should be `"ellipsis_1ha3" in div["class"]` (since the class is a list, not a str). You're probably not reading the HTML correctly, and that's the part you omitted as "not important" ;-) You're also making two requests, one with `urlopen()` (which is what?) and one with `requests.get()` (which is never used).

Comment: i add the real link. if i print(soup) i got the whole html and its corretly too :(. but if i len(mydivs) is the answer 0. i dont see the problem

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct HTML? I get some HTML that looks like the Facebook login screen, and doesn't contain the string `ellipsis_1ha3` anywhere. At any rate, I don't think Facebook allows crawling their website like this. Use their API.

Comment: yes im 100% sure. i try the same with. i add a second example which doesnt works too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `lxml` and xpath expressions to pull out the relevant information.  Beautifulsoup is built on lxml, I believe. Assuming you loaded the document into a string called `html_string`.

```
from lxml import html

h = html.fromstring(html_string)

h.xpath('//div[@class="ellipsis_1ha3"]/node()')
#output:
['20', '30', '10', '50']
```